# UWP App flickers, if installed via Microsoft Store, but not, if installed in program folder

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, firemonkey

I transformed a 64bit-program, created with Delphi XE6 - FireMonkey, manually to the UWP and sent it to the Microsoft Store. When it was published, some users informed me, that all buttons in the app are flickering. I sent them the original 64bit-program and this was working fine on their machine. On my computer both app and program are working fine.
I noticed that the button of the callout-element on my machine looks different in app and program. In the app it has two checkmarks, in the program there is only one checkmark.
What can I do, to solve this problem?

```
This is my appxmanifest.xml:

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
    xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities">
   <Identity Name="..." 
      Version="5.1.0.0"
      ProcessorArchitecture = "x64"
      Publisher="..."/>
   <Properties>
   <DisplayName>...</DisplayName>
   <PublisherDisplayName>...</PublisherDisplayName>
   <Logo>images\small_icon.png</Logo>
</Properties>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="de" />
  </Resources>
    <Dependencies>
      <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop"    MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.17134.765" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust"/>
  </Capabilities>
  <Applications>
  <Application Id="..." Executable="....exe"   EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
    <uap:VisualElements DisplayName=".." Description="...." 
         Square150x150Logo="images\icon.png"   Square44x44Logo="images\small_icon.png" 
          BackgroundColor="#464646" />
    <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="...">
            <uap:Logo>images\small_icon.png</uap:Logo>
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>....</uap:FileType>
          <uap:FileType>....</uap:FileType>       
             <uap:FileType>....</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap:Extension>
      </Extensions>
  </Application>
</Applications>
</Package>
```

Comment: I assume it could be a performance problem. I'm painting in a paintbox. The screen will be updated many times. FireMonkey decides depending on hardware which graphic engine to choose. Could it be, that this differs, if the program runs as app?

Comment: Have you tested to install the converted app with sideload way?

Comment: No, i didn't, because the flickering only occurs on computers of users. They can't install with side load way. The app is not signed und windows doesn't accept appx without signing. On my Computer everything works fine, even if installed with sideload way.

Comment: Based on your description, I think it should be a hardware or environment compatibility issue. Can you find any differences about the OS version, hardware ,environment between your and your no-working customers? Because converted UWP is running in the Sand Box, it has the difference with transitional app in consuming the system component.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I only know three users with this problem. They have very different hardware and are using windows 10 home. One has AMD FX ™ -850 Eight-Core Prozessor 4.00 Ghz and ASUS R9 280 Series, the other Intel Core i5 4210u-1,7GHz and Intel HD Graphics 4400. I am using a virtual machine, but it works for example on a Dell with Intel Core i3 too. I don't have an idea based on hardware.

Comment: I replaced the 64-bit version with a 32-bit version and the flickering disappeared. Now everything works fine. Thank you for your comments!